# Site shows 500 internal error when after installation

Tags: php, .htaccess

I installed a php script on my 1and1 web server but it shows a 500 internal sever error but when index.php is included to the url it loads the normal index.php homepage.
the url is http://my.gsix.com.ng/ but when it is typed this way http://my.gsix.com.ng/index.php it then loads the normal homepage.

I also discovered that it loads well when i first installed it on my localhost before the web server.

EDIT:

My `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png|install|sitemap.xml|robots.txt) 
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f 
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to show us your `.htaccess` file then

Comment: RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png|install|sitemap.xml|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: so what do you think is wrong with the .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

That means that the php script contains some error, try this on top of the script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And it will show you the errors you need to fix.

You can try to remove the .htaccess ( it may be redirecting to a page that doesnt exist )

Comment: It works because it is a real file, his .htaccess is redirecting his routes, for an example /login

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L]
```

**Explaining :**

This enables the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

This checks for existing folders (-d) and files (-f):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

And this does the actual redirecting:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This will redirect every query to the root directory's index.php

Comment: I have the RewriteEngine on in my htaccess

Comment: Do you have 
 RewriteBase / ?

Comment: @MichaelAyoLee can you provide your .htaccess file

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png|install|sitemap.xml|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]   @mooga

Comment: @MichaelAyoLee what is $1? and can you try to make it RewriteEngine on

Comment: <br/>RewriteEngine on<br/>
RewriteCond $1<br/> !^(index.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png|install|sitemap.xml|robots.txt)<br/>
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f<br/>
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d<br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]